# Netty messageReceived() won't get called after a while with long lived connections

Tags: tcp, netty, gprs

***Final Edit / Conclusion***

It was a problem unrelated to netty, still very hard to debug. The worker threads in messageReceived were blocked sometimes, so after some time there were no threads available in the pool.

***Original problem***

At my company we are using netty to listen for connections form GPS Tracking devices. The trackers communicate over GPRS.

We have experienced very strange behaviour of netty 3.2.4-final.

After some time (I can not exactly tell how much, but near to one day) we do not get any message from the trackers. This means the messageReceived method of our implementation of SimpleCahnnelUpstreamHandler won't be called! However if I capture all packets with tcpdump, I can see all messages coming in!

Is this a known issue, that is already fixed in a later version of netty?

Our channel pipeline looks like this:

```
...
final TcpListenerChannelHandler tcpChannelHandler;


@Inject
public TcpListenerPipeline(TcpListenerChannelHandler tcpChannelHandler) {
     this.tcpChannelHandler = tcpChannelHandler;
}

@Override
public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline p = Channels.pipeline();
        p.addLast("frameDecoder", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(2048, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
        p.addLast("encoder", new ByteArrayWrapperEncoder());
        p.addLast("handler", tcpChannelHandler);
        return p;
}
...
```

We instantiate listening in the following way:

```
public void startListen() {
        ChannelFactory channelFactory = new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),20);
        bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(channelFactory);
        bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(pipeline);
        bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
        bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);
        lazyLogger.getLogger().info("Binding Tcp listener to 0.0.0.0 on port '{}'", listenPort);
        serverChannel = bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress("0.0.0.0", listenPort));
}
```

Does anybody have a clue what can be wrong? Or should we just manually disconnect all channel every let's say hour or so?

***EDIT:***

**I have some more info about the problem**

When no messages are processed, it also occurs that channelConnected is not called on successful remote connection. I debugged the problem remotely and found that:

- at NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java line #246
  registerAcceptedChannel(acceptedSocket, currentThread); happens
- the software execution goes all the way through to
  DefaultChannelPipeline line #781 with different events, but my TcpListenerChannelHandler is never int he context.

The most weird is that, sometimes netty notices that a channel is connected, and sometimes it does not.

**EDIT2:**

TcpListenerCahnnelHandler is a simple implementation of SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler

Highlights from it:

```
public class TcpListenerChannelHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {
...
@Override
public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
    super.channelConnected(ctx, e);
    _logger.info("{} device connected from: {}", deviceProtocol.getName(),  ctx.getChannel().getRemoteAddress());
    deviceConnectionRegistry.channelConnected(ctx.getChannel());
}

@Override
public void channelDisconnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
    super.channelDisconnected(ctx, e);
    _logger.info("{} device from endpoint '{}' disconnected.", deviceProtocol.getName(), ctx.getChannel().getRemoteAddress());
    deviceConnectionRegistry.channelDisconnected(ctx.getChannel());
}

@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent messageEvent) throws Exception  {
    super.messageReceived(ctx, messageEvent);

    ...
    NOTE: here we process the meassage, I do not think it can cause any problem
}


@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) throws Exception {
        if(_logger.isWarnEnabled())
            _logger.warn(deviceProtocol.getName()+ " device"
                    +e.getChannel().getRemoteAddress()+" channel", e.getCause());

        if (!(e.getCause() instanceof ConnectException))
            e.getChannel().close();
}
```

In the meanwhile I have upgraded to 3.3.1-final. And If the problem reoccurs i have some idea where to continue debugging.

***EDIT 3:***

I have upgraded to 3.3.1 final, and after two days the same problem reoccurred.

I do not know if it is related, but we have more IP adresses on the same physical interface. Should we try listening on only one interface? Is there any known issues with more eth interfaces?

But again: tcpdump recognizes the message for the trackers, but netty does not call messageReceived in my custom handler.

***EDIT 4:***

I debugged the code further. The problem occurs at NioWorker.java
At line 131 (boolean offered = registerTaskQueue.offer(registerTask);) runs OK, but then the task will never be processed. That means RegisterTask.run() at line 748 will never get called.

Comment: Could you include your custom handlers ?

Comment: I have included the relevant part of the TcpListenerChannelHandler, which is the only custom handler, does this help?

Answer (score 1):

No idea, did you try to add a LoggingHandler to watch everything?
I use to use a custom handler:

```
/**
 *
 * Adapted from the original LoggingHandler in Netty.
 */
public class LoggingHandler implements ChannelUpstreamHandler, ChannelDownstreamHandler {

    String name;
    boolean hexDump;

    public LoggingHandler(String name, boolean hexDump) {
        this.name = name;
        this.hexDump = hexDump;
    }

    /**
     * Logs the specified event to the {@link InternalLogger} returned by
     * {@link #getLogger()}. If hex dump has been enabled for this handler,
     * the hex dump of the {@link ChannelBuffer} in a {@link MessageEvent} will
     * be logged together.
     */
    public void log(ChannelEvent e) {

        String msg = name + " >> " + e.toString();

        // Append hex dump if necessary.
        if (hexDump && e instanceof MessageEvent) {
            MessageEvent me = (MessageEvent) e;
            if (me.getMessage() instanceof ChannelBuffer) {
                ChannelBuffer buf = (ChannelBuffer) me.getMessage();
                msg = msg + " - (HEXDUMP: " + ChannelBuffers.hexDump(buf) + ')';
            }
        }

        // Log the message (and exception if available.)
        if (e instanceof ExceptionEvent) {
            Logger.debug(this, msg, ((ExceptionEvent) e).getCause());
        } else {
            Logger.debug(this, msg);
        }

    }



    public void handleUpstream(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelEvent e)
            throws Exception {
        log(e);
        ctx.sendUpstream(e);
    }

    public void handleDownstream(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelEvent e)
            throws Exception {
        log(e);
        ctx.sendDownstream(e);
    }
```

wich is inserted in both client and server side.
On the server side, I use to add it to both child and parent:

```
ChannelFactory factory = new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(factory);
        bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
        bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);

        bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {

            public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
                ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();
                pipeline.addLast("LOGGER", new LoggingHandler("SERVER", true));
                pipeline.addLast("LAUNCHER", handler.new OnChannelConnectedPlugger());
                return pipeline;
            }
        });
        bootstrap.setParentHandler(new LoggingHandler("SERVER-PARENT", true));
```

Comment: Thanks for the tipp, I will try adding some logging!